# Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file - flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm getting the below error in my code when I try to display the profile image which is connected through my API. how to resolve this. how to display profile picture correctly.

> Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///

//display profile picture

```
 CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 18,
                  child: Image.network(profilePicture,  fit: BoxFit.cover,)),
```

//API integration

```
 List<Map<String, dynamic>>? responseJson;
  var response;
  getdata() async {
    try {
      response = await Dio().get(BASE_API + "user/getUserById/" +loginUserData["id"]!);
      print("response: $response");
      response = json.decode(response.toString());
      for(var items in response){
        responseJson!.add(items);
      }
      setState(() {
        profilePicture = responseJson![0]["profilePicture"]; // new line added
      });
      // print(responseJson['data']['userName']);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Print this profile picture path and search on browser to check if its exist or not. Furthermore image path returning from API usually doesn't contain base URL, if so you need to concatenate base URL in profileImage address.

Answer (score 1):

Print this BASE_API and check if it contains http:// or https:// at the beginning. The Constant BASE_API should contain http:// or https:// at the beginning.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).